Spring webflux sinks is not emitting events on demand but emitting all events in single response
I need support for multiple publishers and multiple subscribers for each publisher.
Below is the controller and service. Sinks is not emitting on demand but it is returning all the events in single response.
where I went wrong in this?
@RestController
public class ActionController {

    @Autowired
    ActionService ActionService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/stream/{input}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> processAction(@PathVariable String input) {
        return ActionService.process(input);
    }
}

@Service
public class ActionService {


    private final Map<String, Sinks.Many<String>> sinks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public void addSink(String input, Sinks.Many<String> sink){
        sinks.put(input, sink);
    }

    public Sinks.Many<String> getSinks(String input){
        return sinks.get(input);
    }


    public Flux<String> process(String input){

        Sinks.Many<String> sink = null;
        if(sinks.get(input)!=null){
            sink= sinks.get(input);
        } else {
            sink = Sinks.many().replay().all();
            sinks.put(input, sink);
            getstrin(sink);
        }
        return sink.asFlux();
    }

    //
    public void getstrin(Sinks.Many<String> sink1){
        Flux.just("chandra","chandra1","chandra2","chandra3","chandra4")
                .doOnNext(i->{
                    sink1.tryEmitNext("chandra1");
                    sink1.tryEmitNext("chandra2");
                    sink1.tryEmitNext("chandra3");
                    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            sink1.tryEmitNext("chandra"+i);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                    sink1.tryEmitComplete();
                }).subscribe();
    }
}


adding subscribeOn as parallel call it started emiting events
Flux.just("chandra","chandra1","chandra2","chandra3","chandra4")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())

